# How to disable diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 in ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar

Tags: java, ssh, diffie-hellman, java-security, ganymede

In Java we are using ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar for connecting to the server via ssh. I need to restrict the weaker algorithm " diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 " specifically.

Is there any customizable settings in ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar that allows to restrict this ?

Is there any java.security setting available for restricting the same ?

Comment: Have a look in my updated answer. Maybe it was not clear what I meant.

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal for a detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot control the server but the library on the client.

Following might be an option

- get the source of the library [ganymed-ssh2-build210-sources.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/ch/ethz/ganymed/ganymed-ssh2/build210/ganymed-ssh2-build210-sources.jar)
- amend `ch/ethz/ssh2/transport/KexManager.java` to not support anymore `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`
- compile the amended code
- create the patched library as `ganymed-ssh2-build210_1.jar` and use this one with the client application

**edit** Find a step-by-step instruction to verify the above.

Assume following structure

```
bin/
apache-sshd-1.6.0.tar.gz
ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar
ganymed-ssh2-build210-sources.jar
SshClientDemo.java
SshServerDemo.java
```

- download the archives
  [choose a mirror for apache-sshd-1.6.0.tar.gz](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/downloads.html)
  [ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/ch/ethz/ganymed/ganymed-ssh2/build210/ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar)
  [ganymed-ssh2-build210-sources.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/ch/ethz/ganymed/ganymed-ssh2/build210/ganymed-ssh2-build210-sources.jar)

**SshServerDemo.java**

```
package sub.optimal;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.sshd.common.NamedFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.common.kex.KeyExchange;
import org.apache.sshd.common.util.GenericUtils;
import org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer;
import org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider;
import org.apache.sshd.server.scp.ScpCommandFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.shell.InteractiveProcessShellFactory;
import org.apache.sshd.server.shell.ProcessShellFactory;

public class SshServerDemo extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Logger.getGlobal().setLevel(Level.FINEST);
        SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setPort(2222);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(
                new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(Paths.get("hostkey.ser"))
        );
        sshd.setShellFactory(InteractiveProcessShellFactory.INSTANCE);
        sshd.setCommandFactory(
                new ScpCommandFactory.Builder().withDelegate(
                        cmd -> new ProcessShellFactory(
                                GenericUtils.split(cmd, ' ')
                        ).create()
                ).build()
        );

        List<NamedFactory<KeyExchange>> keyExchangeFactories;
        keyExchangeFactories = sshd.getKeyExchangeFactories();
        keyExchangeFactories.removeIf(
                e -> !e.getName().equals("diffie-hellman-group1-sha1")
        );

        sshd.setKeyExchangeFactories(keyExchangeFactories);
        sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(
                (username, password, session) -> username.equals(password)
        );

        sshd.start();
        Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
}
```

**SshClientDemo.java**

```
package sub.optimal;

import ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.Session;
import ch.ethz.ssh2.StreamGobbler;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class SshClientDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = new Connection("localhost", 2222);
        conn.connect();
        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword("foo", "foo");
        Session sess = conn.openSession();
        System.out.println("session is authenticated: " + isAuthenticated);

        sess.execCommand("echo I'm there...");

        InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        sess.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

- extract the Apache server

  ```
  tar xzf apache-sshd-1.6.0.tar.gz
  ```
- compile the demo classes

  ```
  javac -cp "apache-sshd-1.6.0/lib/*" -d bin/ SshServerDemo.java
  javac -cp ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar -d bin/ SshClientDemo.java
  ```
- extract the `KexManager.java`

  ```
  jar vxf ganymed-ssh2-build210-sources.jar \
      ch/ethz/ssh2/transport/KexManager.java
  ```
- modify the file `KexManager.java`

  ```
  public static final String[] getDefaultKexAlgorithmList() {
      return new String[] { 
          "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1", 
          "diffie-hellman-group14-sha1"// ,
          // "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"
      };
  }
  ...
  public static final void checkKexAlgorithmList(String[] algos)
      ...
      if ("diffie-hellman-group14-sha1".equals(algos[i]))
          continue;

      // if ("diffie-hellman-group1-sha1".equals(algos[i]))
      //    continue;
      ...
  ```
- compile the patched `KexManager.java`

  ```
  javac -cp ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar ch/ethz/ssh2/transport/KexManager.java
  ```
- create a patched library

  ```
  cp ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar ganymed-ssh2-build210-patched.jar
  jar vuf ganymed-ssh2-build210-patched.jar \
      ch/ethz/ssh2/transport/KexManager.class
  ```

**in command line session ONE**

- start the server

  ```
  java -cp "bin/:apache-sshd-1.6.0/lib/*" sub.optimal.SshServerDemo
  ```

**in command line session TWO**

- check first the key exchange algos supported by the server

  ```
  ssh -vv foo@localhost -p 2222
  ```

  in the output only the `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is reported

  ```
  debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
  ```
- run the client with the **un-patched** library

  ```
  java -cp bin/:ganymed-ssh2-build210.jar sub.optimal.SshClientDemo
  ```

  output

  ```
  session is authenticated: true
  I'm there...
  ```
- run the client with the **patched** library

  ```
  java -cp bin/:ganymed-ssh2-build210-patched.jar sub.optimal.SshClientDemo
  ```

  output

  ```
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot negotiate, proposals do not match.
  ```

  on the server log

  ```
  Unable to negotiate key exchange for kex algorithms \
     (client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 \
     / server: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1)
  ```

That proves that the SshClientDemo with the **patched** library cannot use the key exchange algorithm `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` to connect to the server (which for the PoC only support this one).

Comment: `removeIf(e -> !e.getName().equals("diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"));` should be without `!` before `e`, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You want to change allowed ciphers on the server rather than in your client, otherwise anyone can bypass this easily.

Check answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333728/ssh-how-to-disable-weak-ciphers

Comment: I want the restriction to be in client (java), if the server allows only "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" then we won't connect.

Comment: You need to expand your question a bit then.. Do you want to prevent developers from using specific ciphers or users developing the client for?

Comment: While running the application, the ssh connection establishment should not allow " diffie-hellman-group1-sha1"

Comment: That did not really answer my question.. but hard to give you an example without any code or more info of what the runnin "application" is..

Comment: To be specific, want the client developers to restrict access as said.